# Why does segmenation fault occur?

Tags: c

I made an AA tree, and when deleting a large number of elements in a loop, this error occurs, how can I fix it? If you delete it separately (not from the loop), this error does not occur, how can you remove it? Maybe the call stack is overflowing or something else, there was no such thing during an insert or search operation

```
main.c

int main() {

  FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
  AATree aat = NULL;

  std::clock_t start;
  double duration;

  for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
    aat_insertData(&aat, i);
  }


  start = std::clock();

  for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    aat_deleteData(&aat, i);
  }
  duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

Function delete

```
AATree _DeleteData(AATree t, int key)
{
    AATree m;
    if (t == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (key < t->key)                                       // Firstly, Find the node that you want to delete.
    {
        t->left = _DeleteData(t->left, key);
    }
    else if (key > t->key)
    {
        t->right = _DeleteData(t->right, key);
    }
    else {                                                  
        if (t->left == NULL && t->right == NULL)      
        {
            free(t);
            return NULL;                                    
        }
        if (t->left == NULL)                            
        {
            AATree l;
            l = Successor(t); 
            t->key = l->key;                                
            t->right = _DeleteData(t->right, l->key);      
        }
        else {
            AATree l;
            l = Predecessor(t); 
            t->key = l->key;                               
            t->left = _DeleteData(t->left, l->key); 
        } 
    }
    if ((t->level > 1) && (t->left == NULL || t->right == NULL)) {
      t->level--;
      t = Decrease_level(t);
      t = Skew(t);
      t = Split(t);
    }
    t = Decrease_level(t);
    t = Skew(t);
    m = t->right;
    t->right = Skew(m);
    if (m != NULL && m->right != NULL)
    {
        t->right->right = Skew(m->right);
    }
    t = Split(t);
    t->right = Split(m);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: This is what a debugger is for.  I would spend time time learning how to debug a program.

Comment: Which language? The file is `main.c` but contains `std::clock_t start;`

Comment: Used a couple of functions from C ++ the rest is all with

Comment: you cannot mix C++ specific functions with C

Comment: Hi Rumeone. Welcome to SO and C(++). Please give the complete source.